# Java File permissions to deny deletion

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions

I would like to require admin rights in order to delete a file I created via my java code.
Just as you have it with .dll files in program installation directories for example.

So, if you click on delete, it will ask you for administrator permissions.

Setting it to ReadOnly, deny writing or executing doesnt change anything after all.

Is this possible using Windows NTFS system somehow?

I was not able to find any solution for this. Is there even a "delete" permission?

Comment: If Windows is like Unix in this regard, then it is not the permissions of the file itself that control deletion, but rather the permissions on its directory.  Or more precisely, the permissions on the directory whose entry for the file you want to delete.  There may be more than one directory with an entry for the file.